# Regex works in grep, but not in sed

Tags: regex, sed, grep, non-greedy

I created the following regex which I am able to successfully use to grab a substring, but not to substitute it with sed.

```
test@devs-ops01:~$ grep -Eo "server\shost-gso121.*?:[0-9]{4}\s;" upstream_clusters.conf
server host-gso121.domain.com:8080 ;
```

When I try to use the same regex in sed, it doesn't catch it:

```
test@devs-ops01:~$ sed 's/server\shost-gso121.*?:[0-9]{4}\s;//' upstream_clusters.conf
upstream service_cluster {


    server host-gso120.domain.com:8080 ;server host-gso121.domain.com:8080 ;

    keepalive 8;
}
```

And yet, if i just write the name of the server without all of the special functions, the sed command does catch it:

```
test@devs-ops01:~$ sed 's/host-gso121//' upstream_clusters.conf
upstream service_cluster {


    server host-gso120.domain.com:8080 ;server .domain.com:8080 ;

    keepalive 8;
}
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try enabling the "extended regexp" mode with `sed -E`

Comment: You are using ERE (extended regular expressions) with `-E` in `grep` but not in `sed`. (Note: OS X doesn't seem to support `*?` in `sed` ERE, but does in `grep` ERE.)

Comment: Frugal quantifiers aren't supported in sed, even with `-E`/`-r`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had success with both -r and -E in ubuntu on (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: Also, this isn't really related to `bash`.

Comment: Could you make an answer from the solution which helped? I would like this to get out of the unanswered Q/A list.

Comment: @yunnosch - Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zeppelin solution solved this for me.

```
sed -E
```